# Where the vales like Userid and passwords are stored in SSO of BTDF

Tags: biztalk, biztalk2006r2, btdf

I have a query regarding BTDF SSO config setting. I am beginner with BizTalk.

I am looking for SSO storage where credentials are stored and retrieved from SSO. I have built-in app located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Deployment Framework for BizTalk 6.0\Framework\DeployToolsork\DeployTools`

Could anyone tell me how to store and retrieve from existing SSO config like SSOSettingsEditor which is the default provided by BTDF.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear.  Are you asking where SSO storage is or how to retrieve/edit them?  SSO storage is in the SSO database.  A tool to create/view/edit them is the SSO Configuration Application MMC Snap-In https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14524  P.S.  BizTalk 2006 R2?  Isn't that in extended support now?  Time to migrate to a new version

Comment: You are right. I want to retrieve/edit SSO Storage of current BTDF application. I need to set password that i am generating to SSO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using BTDF, you can store your configurations as provided in SettingsFileGenerator.xml in BizTalk SSODB. BTDF automatically store your configuration if IncludeSSO property is set to true in btdfproj file.

If you have provided your credential details in SettingsFileGenerator.xml file then only you will find them in SSODB.

You should use SSOSettingsEditor to retrieve or make changes to the configurations. In SSOSettingsEditor, type in your application name and press enter.

Refer to link: [BTDF IncludeSSO](http://www.tfabraham.com/BTDFDocs/V5_0/DeploymentFrameworkForBizTalkDocs.html?DeployConfigurationSettingsintoS.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
I want to retrieve/edit SSO Storage of current BTDF SSOSettingsEditor. I need to set password that i am generating in SSO. Any idea regards to this ?

Comment: How did you generate the password? Did you deploy an app using BTDF, can you elaborate more about yr problem?

Comment: I am generating password through separate app or a class library. I need to consume and set generated password to SSO DB and then can be set or updated to Settingsfile.xml on scheduled basis say 45 or 60 days.

Comment: In that case, Use generated settings.xml file to update the password using ssosettingsfileimport.Exe SSOSettingsFileImport.exe affiliateAppName:"Appname" /settingsFile:"..\..\EnvironmentSettings\DEV_Settings.xml"

Answer (score 0):

BTDF provides a [library](https://biztalkdeployment.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Dev/V6_0/Tools/SSOSettingsFileImport/SSOSettingsFileImport/SSOSettingsManager.cs) for modifying SSO Settings that it uses.  The method is uses is slightly different from the default Microsoft sample SSO client, so take care regarding which one you're using.

Per that link, the class provides these methods:

```cs
namespace SSOSettingsFileManager
{
    public static class SSOSettingsManager
    {
        public static void WriteSetting(string affiliateApplication, string propertyName, string propertyValue);
    }
}
```

It should be fairly straightforward to call that method once you've added a reference to the SSOSettingsFileReader.dll in whatever C# project you have generating your password or updating it, i.e.

```cs
string newPassword = GenerateMyPassword();
SSOSettingsFileManager.SSOSettingsManager.WriteSetting("MyApplicationName", "Password", newPassword;);
```

You could also look at the source of how he's doing it if you want to implement the method yourself.